# How do I set a version for my jar in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, versioning

I am using gradle to build a java project, which outputs a jar.

What is the appropriate way to set a version for the jar, so it is included in the jar file name as well?

Comment: It should be enough to simply set the project version (i.e. `version = "xxx"`).

Answer (score 0):

Working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_65055591) using Gradle 6.7

This is a minimal example (using [this doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html)):

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

jar {
    archiveBaseName = 'myproject'
    archiveVersion = '5.1.50'
}
```

the output is `build/libs/myproject-5.1.50.jar`.

Comment: Note that `archiveVersion` will, by default, use the `project.version` value when the `java` plugin is applied.